# Where is vector in MathNet for f#

Tags: f#, mathnet-numerics

I am using Visual Studio 2017. I get an error on vector below:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   FS0039  The value or constructor 'vector' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following:
   Vector   TestFSharp  c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\TestFSharp\TestFSharp\Program.fs   88  Active
```

The program:

```
open System
open System.Net

open MathNet
open MathNet.Numerics
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double

let v = vector [ 1.0; 2.0; 3.0 ]
```

Comment: I haven't worked with Math.NET, but by quick glance at their F# script example (https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/src/FSharpExamples/Vectors.fsx): Are you referencing the MathNet.Numerics.FSharp.dll for the F# APIs? If so, I can also see the example opens `MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra` namespace/module which is missing in your code.

Comment: Thanks that is the problem.

Comment: You're welcome. Which one was the problem? Or was it both the dll and the namespace? Now that we know it worked, I'd like to make it an answer so that your question doesn't remain unanswered

Comment: I was forgetting to say "open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `vector` function is defined in `MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra`, you need to open that namespace as well.